# why isnt my regex matching the below numerical strings?

Tags: python, regex

if I use the money_conversion func on $17 million, it returns 17000000 etc, only when its a single digit does it return an incorrect match i.e. $7 million converts to 7 instead of 7000000

```
import re

number = r'\d+(,\d{3})*\.*\d*'                     #$790,000
amount = r'thousand|million|billion'                #$12.2 million example

word_re = rf'\${number}(-|\sto\s|–)?(\$*{number})\s?({amount})'
value_re = rf'\${number}'

def parse_word_syntax(string):
    value_string = re.search(number,string).group()
    value = float(value_string.replace(',',''))
    word = re.search(amount,string,flags=re.I).group().lower()
    word_value = word_to_value(word)
    return value * word_value

def word_to_value(word):
    value_dict ={'thousand':1000,'million':1000000,'billion':1000000000}
    return value_dict[word]

def parse_value_syntax(string):
    value_string = re.search(number,string).group()
    value = float(value_string.replace(',',''))
    return value

def money_conversion(money):
    if money == 'N/A':
        return None
    
    if isinstance(money,list):
        money = money[0]
        
    word_syntax = re.search(word_re,money,flags=re.I)
    value_syntax = re.search(value_re,money)
    
    if word_syntax:
        print('converting word object to numerics')
        return parse_word_syntax(word_syntax.group())
    
    elif value_syntax:
        print('converting float objects to numerics')
        return parse_value_syntax(value_syntax.group())
    
    else:
        return None
'''
```

Comment: Why do you need `re` here? You can: (1) check that first char is `$`, (2) parts = str.split by ' ' (3) convert parts[1] to a factor (million, billion, etc to number), (4) multiply parts[0] by that number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is quite simple: your regex does not match the `word_re` regex that looks like `\$\d+(,\d{3})*\.*\d*(-|\sto\s|–)?(\$*\d+(,\d{3})*\.*\d*)\s?(thousand|million|billion)`, see [its demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZdgcFv/1). You tried to make each subsequent pattern part optional, and you forgot the `\d+` from the `number` variable block requires matching at least one digit, and since `word_re` contains two occurrences of `number`, the whole resulting regex requires at least two digits.

You need use

```py
number = r'\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?'
word_re = rf'\${number}(?:(?:-|\sto\s|–)\${number})?\s*({amount})'
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/93QbYI).

- `\$\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?` - matches `$`, one or more digits, then zero or more repetitions of a comma and three digit chunk, and then an optional `.` and one or more digits
- `(?:(?:-|\sto\s|–)\$\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `(?:-|\sto\s|–)` - `-`, whitespace+`to`+whitespace, or `–`
  - `\$` - a `$` char
  - `\d+(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?` - see above
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(thousand|million|billion)` - one of the three strings.